# How to get my local pc imagepath

Tags: php

When we upload an image

how do I get full path of my local PC in php

For example

C:\Users\aa\Downloads\desert.jpg

Comment: what you done in coding for this task?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, period. Only the image itself is uploaded, its path of origin is a) irrelevant and b) none of your business and not transmitted. The browser does not divulge information about the local file system for security reasons.